# Use a custom deserializer only on certain fields?

Tags: gson

With gson, is it possible to use a custom deserializer / serializer only on certain fields? The [user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) shows how to register an adapter for an entire type, not for specific fields. The reason why I want this is because I parse a custom date format and store it in a `long` member field (as a Unix timestamp), so I don't want to register a type adapter for all `Long` fields.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also store Date values as `long` in my objects for easy defensive copies. I also desired a way to override only the date fields when serializing my object and not having to write out all the fields in the process. This is the solution I came up with. Not sure it is the optimal way to handle this, but it seems to perform just fine.

The `DateUtil` class is a custom class used here to get a `Date` parsed as a `String`.

```
public final class Person {
  private final String firstName;
  private final String lastName;
  private final long birthDate;

  private Person(String firstName, String lastName, Date birthDate) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.birthDate = birthDate.getTime();
  }

  public static Person getInstance(String firstName, String lastName, Date birthDate) {
    return new Person(firstName, lastName, birthDate);
  }

  public String toJson() {
    return new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Person.class, new PersonSerializer()).create().toJson(this);
  }

  public static class PersonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Person> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Person person, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
      JsonElement personJson = new Gson().toJsonTree(person);
      personJson.getAsJsonObject().add("birthDate", new JsonPrimitive(DateUtil.getFormattedDate(new Date(policy.birthDate), DateFormat.USA_DATE)));
      return personJson;
    }
  }
}
```

When the class is serialized, the `birthDate` field is returned as a formatted `String` instead of the `long` value.

Comment: The problem with this is the `new Gson()` for delegation. If I could use the existing gson (which might have it's own customizations apart from this type adapter), that'd be the perfect solution. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mar0ux, I see your point. Unless the `Gson` object was a static member of the class, I really don't see how that could work. I don't really use Gson that much anymore. I have switched over to Jackson since it has good integration with Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store it as a `long`, use a custom type with a proper adapter. Inside your type, represent your data any way you want -- a `long`, why not.

Comment: I thought about that, but I think it's a bit cumbersome to write a wrapper around Long.

Comment: It's not a wrapper. Your actual object, semantically speaking, is NOT a long integer. From an OOP point of view, using a long to represent it should be an internal implementation detail of no concern to the external code. Directly using a long would be *unwrapping*.

Comment: The data I'm storing is the number of milliseconds since the January 1st, 1970. And yes, that is a long integer, semantically speaking.

Comment: A number you're are using to represent a date. Do what you will, though, I was here to help, not to argue.

Comment: @Felix: Actually, java.util.Date is also just a wrapper around milliseconds since the Epoch, unfortunately, it's mutable and also otherwise broken. So I'd also suggest to use an object (your own `ImmutableDate` or anything else), unless you badly need to conserve memory.