# GSON java how can i make different names between mapping and printing?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "aggregation": {
    "CityAgg" : {
      "key" : "Paris"
    }
  }
}
```

I create mapping and for each field, I add a `@SerializedName` because I want to create custom names for my variables.

For example in the JSON, there is a key names `key`, but I want my variable in Java to be `cityName`.

So, I do this:

```
@SerializedName("key")
public String cityName
```

I can dynamically map the response JSON to my objects like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Query2 query2 = gson.fromJson(response, Query2.class);
```

It is working perfectly.

However, when I want to print the mapped object, I do this:

```
String query2String = gson.toJson(query2);
Gson gsonPretty = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String prettyJson = gsonPretty.toJson(query2String);
```

The problem is that, in the `prettyJson`, I can see the `key`, not `cityName`.

I would like to know if there is a way to customize that. I don't want to see `key`.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization Using [`alternate`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html#alternate--) could also work

Comment: @RC. there is no annotation called alternate

Comment: @RC.  i did this: @SerializedName(value = "CityAgg", alternate = "city"), but i can still see that `CityAgg` is being prineted, not `city`

Comment: @AniaDavid Simple hack is change the annotation value during `PrettyPrint()` and do it back after using... :) Using Reflection

Comment: @RC. sounds like alternate is not for printing, thanks for going also

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to write custom serializer / deserializer class as [Viswanath Lekshmanan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870173/viswanath-lekshmanan) has mentioned, you can always create some kind of DTO object.

Your domain classes:

```
class CityAgg {
    @SerializedName("key")
    protected String cityName;

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }
}

class Aggregation {
    @SerializedName("CityAgg")
    protected CityAgg cityAgg;

    public CityAgg getCityAgg() {
        return cityAgg;
    }
}

class Query2 {
    @SerializedName("aggregation")
    protected Aggregation aggregation;

    public Aggregation getAggregation() {
        return aggregation;
    }
}
```

Sample DTO class:

```
class CityAggDto {
    protected String cityName;

    public CityAggDto(CityAgg query2) {
        this.cityName = query2.getCityName();
    }
}
```

Sample use:

```
String response = "{ \"aggregation\": { \"CityAgg\": { \"key\": \"value\" } } }";

Gson gson = new Gson();
Gson gsonPretty = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

Query2 query2 = gson.fromJson(response, Query2.class);
CityAggDto cityAggDto = new CityAggDto(query2.getAggregation().getCityAgg());

String cityAggDtoJson = gson.toJson(cityAggDto);
String cityAggDtoPrettyJson = gsonPretty.toJson(cityAggDto);

Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + cityAggDtoJson);
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + cityAggDtoPrettyJson);
```

Result:

[image]

`@SerializationName` annotation is being used for both operations - serialization and deserialization - that is why your JSON strings contains `key` key.

It is sad that, regardless of that `@SerializationName` annotation can be used with methods - using different values for getters and setters won't work as GSON is fields-based only:

> Using fields vs getters to indicate Json elements
>
> Some Json libraries use the getters of a type to deduce the Json elements. We chose to use all fields (up the inheritance hierarchy) that are not transient, static, or synthetic. We did this because not all classes are written with suitably named getters. Moreover, getXXX or isXXX might be semantic rather than indicating properties.
>
> However, there are good arguments to support properties as well. We intend to enhance Gson in a latter version to support properties as an alternate mapping for indicating Json fields. For now, Gson is fields-based.

Source: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/GsonDesignDocument.md

That's why I have switched to Jackson. :)

Answer (score 0):

Either You should use a [Custom Deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841645/use-a-custom-deserializer-only-on-certain-fields) or You should alter the value of annotation using  Reflection.

Update: Worst solution

Using Reflection looks like this

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{YourClass.class.getResource("YourClass.class")});
    Class locAnnotation = classLoader.loadClass("yourPackage.Query2");

    Field field = locAnnotation.getDeclaredField("cityName");
    final Annotation fieldAnnotation = field.getAnnotation(SerializedName.class);
    changeAnnotationValue(fieldAnnotation, "oldValue", "newValue");


public static Object changeAnnotationValue(Annotation annotation, String key, Object newValue) {
    Object handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation);
    Field f;
    try {
        f = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Map<String, Object> memberValues;
    try {
        memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) f.get(handler);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    Object oldValue = memberValues.get(key);
    if (oldValue == null || oldValue.getClass() != newValue.getClass()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    memberValues.put(key, newValue);
    return oldValue;
}
```

Comment: could you provide a solution? the answer you provided i couldn't find soltin.