# How to convert json string to java object, if json property name and java object property are different

Tags: java, json

I have one Json String like below :

```
 String empJson= {"id":"13480","name":"test","salary":29292"}
```

I want to convert above json string into Java object.

**Emp.Java**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Emp {
 @XmlElement(name="name")
 private String m_name;
 @XmlElement(name="id")
 private String m_id;
 @XmlElement(name="salary")
 private String m_salary;
 //setters and getters
}



 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    JsonElement jElement = gson.fromJson(empJson, JsonElement.class);
    System.out.println(jElement);
    Emp = gson.fromJson(jElement, Emp.class);
    System.out.println(" id : " + emp.getId());
```

But Emp object returning null values for all the fields .

Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Your JSON String is not valid `{"id":"13480","name":"test","salary":29292"}` should be `"{\"id\":\"13480\",\"name\":\"test\",\"salary\":29292}"`.

Comment: Try `@SerializedName` and see example in [What is the basic purpose of @SerializedName annotation in Android using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957285/what-is-the-basic-purpose-of-serializedname-annotation-in-android-using-gson).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327636/gson-java-how-can-i-make-different-names-between-mapping-and-printing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try after fixing input Json string

```
 String empJson= {"id":"13480","name":"test","salary":"29292"}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using ObjectMapper and JaxbAnnotationModule I have resolved my isssue.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Emp emp = mapper.readValue(jsonObject.toString(), Emp.class);
System.out.println("EmpName: " + emp.getName());
```